# Android, change alpha on touch

Tags: android

I set the alpha of my image view like so:

```
myImageView.setAlpha(0);
```

Then on touch:

```
myImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
v.setAlpha(100);
```

But the alpha doesn't change when I touch the image, I know the touch is picked up as I can log a string to check.

---

### EDIT

If I set my original alpha to 0 and then add a fade in animation, the fade in animation doesnt work, here's the animation:

```
fadeInAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.00f, 1.00f);
fadeInAnimation.setDuration(1000);
```

If I set the alpha of the original view to something like 0.10 then it fades from 0 to 0.10 not all the way to 1.00f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setAlpha` takes a float from `0` to `1` where 0 means completely transparent and 1 means fully opaque.  Try an input of `0.5f` and see what happens.

EDIT:

One way to implement an Animation Listener:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity{

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle noNeed){
      **** setup ****
      fadeInAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.00f, 1.00f);
      fadeInAnimation.setDuration(1000);
      fadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new myAnimationListener());
   }


   private class myAnimationListener implement Animation.AnimationListener{
      public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation){
         ** Do stuff you want to do just before the animation **
      }

      public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation){
         ** Do stuff you want to do as an animation repeats itself
            (i.e. it has started and finish at least once and will go again) **
      }

      public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation){
         ** Do stuff you want to do once an animation finishes **
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Great, this works. But I have edit my original question for animation

Comment: I *think* the reason for your animation problem is you don't need to set the Alpha of the image view for the animation.  The numbers in the animation represent a percentage of the max alpha (the alpha you set).  When you set the alpha to `.1`, your max is `.1` so in the animation `0.00f` to `1.00` is a range of `0` to `.1`.  Set the alpha of the view to `1.0` and your animation will range from `0` to `1`.

Comment: I see, but when I set the alpha to 1, the animation works but it starts off showing, I want it to start off hidden (alpha 0) and then fade in.

Comment: Keep it 0 right up to the point you want to animate.  Then set it to 1.  The image shouldn't become unless you call `invalidate()`.

Comment: Great, works, just one more thing, im getting it to fade out with:    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                  v.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
                  
                 break;
The fade out works, but once its faded out, it goes back to full alpha again, is there a way to set the alpha to 0 once the animation is complete?

Comment: Implement an Animation Listener. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html.  You can set it to 0 again in onAnimationEnd (You should be able to use onAnimationStart to set it to 1 too.  Would make things cleaner).

Comment: Ive tried v.onAnimationEnd(Animation fadeInAnimation){
                   
                  } but no luck, do you have an example? Do I have to set it in the onTouch or when I declare the animation?

Comment: @beans I edited my post to include a way to implement the AnimationLListener.  Just do what we discussed earlier.